# Django Reverse Not Found when reversing a url in main app

Tags: python, django, url, django-views, reverse

I can not get my head around why this simple reverse() call for one of my Django-Views is not working. The error occurs in some of my tests:

Reverse code snippet:

```
# myapp/tests.py
response = self.client.get(reverse('index', args=()))
```

URL registry:

```
# myapp/urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, 'index'),
    path('configuration/', include('configuration.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

view:

```
#myapp/views.py
def index(request):
    elements_list = DB_ELEMENTS.objects.all()
    return render(request, "startpage.html", {'elements': elements_list})
```

The error I keep getting is 
`Reverse for 'index' not found. 'index' is not a valid view function or pattern name.`

Any help appreciated.

Comment: try `path('', views.index, name='index'),`

Comment: The path `''` does not have any arguments (e.g. `<int:pk>`), therefore you won't be able to reverse it with `args=([element1],)`.

Comment: thanks, this did the trick. Also, I passed arguments via args which were not expected by the executed view function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#reverse-resolution-of-urls): One needs to use the **name** keyword argument (kwarg):

```
# myapp/urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('configuration/', include('configuration.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```